# Link Sharepoint List to Excel to be used as a project template in MS Project 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, project-server

I am using online version of MS Project 2013 and Sharepoint 2013 to create a PWA level workflow. I have a created a dummy project that I wish to save as a site template to be used for my enterprise project.
In the template project site, I want to link a Sharepoint List to an excel. Can I do that, if yes, how?

The issue is with dynamic linking for each new project I create, a new list is created on a newly created site online. How can we have the excel reference the list address?

Thank you in advance for your help